# Base64 image to WebGL context (for readPixels)

Tags: javascript, performance, canvas, computer-vision, webgl

An image comes in Base64 format, and I want to compare pixel relations.

After reading about how GPUs work, I think this type of analysis would perform best in a canvas `webgl` context, rather than `2d` as I was using before. I haven't used WebGL before, and I know it's really low level.

Does anyone know of an efficient way to put **Base64 into a `webgl` context, where I can .readPixels** and iterate / compare with these 1 million pixels?

Thanks

Comment: If you haven't used WebGL before then you're asking way too broad of a question. It's like saying "I've never programmed before. Tell me how to compare images". First you need to [learn webgl](http://webglfundamentals.org) then come back and ask less broad question.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is put the image(s) into a texture, compute differences with a shader and than read them from framebuffer (with `readPixels`) and sum them to, for example, calculate error.

To put Base64 encoded image, you need to create an `Image` object and then assign it to a texture:

```
var image = new Image();
// You can omit using onload and asynchronous code,
// but unfortunately it's not fully reliable :(
image.onload = function () {
    /* ... */
};
// Here you'll need to know format of the image (png, jpeg...).
image.src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + base64EncodedImage;

// gl here is the context
var textureId = gl.createTexture();
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE2D, texture);
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE2D, /* ... */, image);
```

After that you can use uploaded images (and even rendered ones) to compute a diff with, for example, that shader:

```
// texture coordinates
varying vec2 uv;

uniform sampler2D texture1;
uniform sampler2D texture2;

void main(void) {
    vec4 texel1 = texture2D(texture1, uv);
    vec4 texel2 = texture2D(texture2, uv);
    gl_FragColor = abs(texel1 - texel2);
}
```

Than you read diff data from the framebuffer:

```
var diffData = new Uint8Array();
gl.readPixels(/* ... */, diffData);

// Process diffData...
```

However, if it's your first time with WebGL I strongly suggest to follow gman's advise and to learn WebGL itself. It's a powerful technology and knowing it would be a good tool in your toolbox:)